# Column' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have tried to run this query as I am using the Sum function to get the invoices with the specified customer respectively.

When I tried to run the query- I get the below error.

> Column 'ConsumerMST_LKO.CustomerName' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT       c.customerid, 
             c.customername, 
             totalamt, 
             Sum(invoice.totalamt) AS total, 
             invoice.invoiceno, 
             invoice.invoicedate, 
             invoice.invoicemonth, 
             invoice.totalamt 
FROM             consumermst_lko AS c 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN invoicedetails  AS invoice 
ON               c.customerid = invoice.customerid 
WHERE            c.customerid='LKO00028153' 
GROUP BY         c.customerid FOR json auto
```

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems really clear to me.

Comment: maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can help you

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you please tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Looks like you have your order of operation wrong. Select on the consumer_lko table and group by your consumerst_lko information.  Then join that result on the  invoicedetails table.

Comment: If you're selecting `totalamt` and `SUM(totalamt)`, even it you get the `GROUP BY` clause right I don't believe this is going to yield the results you're looking for. Are you looking for a running total?

Comment: yes, i need to get the total amount of the invoices respective to the specifiied customer. @EricBrandt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column must appear in the `FROM` clause of the `SELECT` statement, but is not required to appear in the SELECT list.
You can know more in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)   about the valid expression in the clause `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT       c.customerid, 
                 c.customername, 
                 totalamt, 
                .
                .
                .
    FROM             consumermst_lko AS c 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN invoicedetails  AS invoice 
    ON               c.customerid = invoice.customerid 
    WHERE            c.customerid='LKO00028153' 
    GROUP BY         c.customerid
                   , c.customername,...
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a running total, regular aggregate functions won't work by themselves. The easiest way to get there is with Windowing functions.

The clause after the `SUM` function tells the engine to calculate a sum, partitioned by (broken up by) `customerid` and ordered by `invoicedate`. Without sample data, I'm not sure if this is quite right, but if you play around with it on your system it should get you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT
  c.customerid, 
  c.customername, 
  totalamt, --<--This should be qualified with a table alias. Redundant?
  SUM(i.totalamt) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customerid ORDER BY i.invoicedate) AS total, 
  i.invoiceno, 
  i.invoicedate, 
  i.invoicemonth, 
  i.totalamt 
FROM             consumermst_lko AS c 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN invoicedetails  AS i 
ON               c.customerid = i.customerid 
WHERE            c.customerid='LKO00028153' FOR JSON AUTO
```